# Where to place tesseract language files and what would the datapath string look like?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, tesseract

In my Xamarin Android Application, I've been trying to call an image and tesseract language files and it keeps returning null. I don't know exactly where to place the files, and how the datapath string would look like.

I've tried placing it under resources and in an asset folder and when I run it it's not found.

```
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Start");
            var engine = new TesseractEngine(@"./tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.Default);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Started Engine");
```

I expect it to not stop when I try to initialize the Tesseract Engine.

---

[image]

Comment: I believe that you need to copy them from Assets to an app folder at startup